# Gem install failed in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-10.04

I am running Ubuntu10.04 LTS behind a proxy that required authentication. I have set up `$http_proxy` environment variable for command line to access the Internet.

When running `sudo gem install haml`, it produced the following error:

```
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'haml' (>= 0) in any repository
```

I have also tired other commands such as `wget` and `gem query -r`, they were executed correctly.

I have also tired the same setup in Ubuntu 8.04.4 LTS, they all seems to work.

Does anyone has the similar issue in Ubuntu 10.04 LTS?

Answer (score 0):

Try first by setting http_proxy. If you are not root, try with sudo first

```
root@ubuntu:~# **export http_proxy=http://your.proxy.net:3128**
root@ubuntu:~# gem install ruby-debug ruby-debug-base ruby-debug-ide
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed columnize-0.3.2
Successfully installed linecache-0.43
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, didn´t read that your proxy needs authentication. In the rubygems page they talk about authenticating proxies, and problems with NTLM (Microsoft) authentication.

You can give a try: http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/15#page67